# Python Dict Key/ Value Grabbing

Tags: python, json

I am currently new to Python.

I am making a dictionary app to learn.

However, I am having trouble getting the right output in one of my functions.

I want the user to input a word and get the word (key) and the definition (value) back in return.

The JSON file I am pulling from can be found here: https://github.com/prestonjohnson17/Dictionary

```
import json

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

type(data)

def finding_def():                       
    user_word = data[input(str())]       
    if data.keys() == user_word:         
        print(user_word)                 
    else:                                
        print ("not a real word")

finding_def()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the key is present in the dictionary, and then get the value for that key (Although as I saw the JSON file, the value itself is an array; You should handle printing all entries of the array).

```
def finding_def():                       
    user_word = input()    
    if user_word in data:
        print("Entries:")
        for entry in data[user_word]:     
            print(entry)                 
    else:                                
        print("not a real word")

finding_def()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that was a lot simpler than the approach I was trying to take.

Answer (score 1):

This is cleaver but loses some of the readability in the process.

```py
import json

data = json.load(open("data.json"))
print(data.get(input(), "not a real word"))
```

Comment: There is no `raw_input()` builtins in `python 3.x`. Please replace it with `input()`

Comment: good catch forgot this laptop is on 2.7! I need to fix that...

Comment: @PrestonJohnson Really verbosity is better than cleverness... .get() is a bit of magical function which is unknown by some python programmers and  users of other languages may not understand what is going on there, NajafiMH solution (currently accepted) is well written and easy to understand. And if you are unfortunate to be paid by the line of code, or your performance reviews are based on quantity, pretty verbose code pays off...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import json

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def finding_def():                       
    user_word = input("Enter word: ")
    value = data.get(user_word, "not a real word")
    print(value)

finding_def()
```